# sending application/x-protobuf file in python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I am writing a mitmproxy  script that intercept a  application/x-protobuf file and  make some modification then forward it to the client.
here is the code:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
from libmproxy.protocol.http import decoded
import re
def response(context, flow):

    if flow.response.headers.get_first("content-type", "").startswith('application/x-protobuf'):
      with decoded(flow.response):
         data=flow.response.content
         data2=re.sub('"http://.*?"','"http://some other url"' ,data)
         flow.response.content=data2
```

However when the client receive the file it throw "Failed to parse input." error

Comment: It was just for testing.I forgot to remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the problem:

```
re.sub('"http://.*?"','"http://some other url"' ,data)
```

You can't use a regex to rewrite a URL embedded in a protobuf. Protobuf is a binary encoding which uses length-based delimiters. So, for example, when a string is embedded in a protobuf, it is prefixed by the length. If you use a regex to change the string, then the length will be wrong. Note that you can't just change the length too because the length of the parent object might still be wrong, etc.

You will need to decode the protobuf data using the Protobuf Python library, edit the fields you need to change, then re-encode it.

Comment: Can you  show me an example please. I searched all over the internet but I could not find something clear.

Comment: @Gray You'll need to learn how to use the Protobuf library. You will need the `.proto` file defining the exact payload message type, which you'll run through the protocol compiler (`protoc`) to generate Python code specific to the schema. Then you can use that code to parse the message, modify it, and serialize it again. Unfortunately this is not a three-liner that you can just copy/paste.